# Don't implement all abstract method

Tags: python, inheritance, abstract-class

I have a multiple sub classes that all inherit from the same base class.
Some of the base class methods are empty to be implemented by some sub classes, but not all of them.

In this rudimentary example, `FirstChild` re-implements `do_a_barrel_roll()`,
while `SecondChild` re-implements `dont_do_a_barrel_roll()`

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        ...

    def do_a_barrel_roll(self):
        pass

    def dont_do_a_barrel_roll(self):
        pass

    def say_hi(self):
        return "Hello"


class FirstChild(Parent):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def do_a_barrel_roll(self):
        ...
        return 42

class SecondChild(Parent):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def dont_do_a_barrel_roll(self):
        ...
        return 0
```

Now I would like to make the `Parent` class an abstract class and thereby make the two empty methods abstract methods.

This is roughly what I want:

```
class Parent(ABC):
    def __init__(self):
        ...


    @abstractmethod
    def do_a_barrel_roll(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def dont_do_a_barrel_roll(self):
        pass

    def say_hi(self):
        return "Hello"


class FirstChild(Parent):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def do_a_barrel_roll(self):
        ...
        return 42

   # ignore implementation of second abstract method

class SecondChild(Parent):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    # ignore implementation of first abstract method

    def dont_do_a_barrel_roll(self):
        ...
        return 0
```

Unfortunately, Python wants me to implement every single abstract method for every single sub class, which I don't want to do due to the complexity of the actual code (1500+ lines of code, not he silly example above).

Is there a clean and easy way where I don't have to do that?

Comment: Split up your base class, you can always do multiple inheritance for the classes that *need* all of the methods.

Comment: does that also work, when the abstract methods are called from the base class?

Comment: If you are using `super` properly, sure. The only thing special about an abstract method is that its name is added to a list which, when you try to instantiate a subclass, is checked to verify that a non-abstract definition has been found for that name.

Comment: Could you provide a code example of what that may look like?

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to implement one of the two abstract methods, you should define two abstract base classes, one per method.

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        ...

    def say_hi(self):
        return "Hello"


class BarrelRollingParent(Parent, ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def do_a_barrel_roll(self):
        pass


class NonBarrelRollingParent(Parent, ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def dont_do_a_barrel_roll(self):
        pass


class FirstChild(BarrelRollingParent):
    def do_a_barrel_roll(self):
        ...
        return 42


class SecondChild(NonBarrelRollingParent):
    def dont_do_a_barrel_roll(self):
        ...
        return 0
```

You can always inherit from both classes if you want to require both methods to be implemented.

```
class ThirdChild(BarrelRollingParent, NonBarrelRollingParent):
    def do_a_barrel_roll(self):
        ...

    def dont_do_a_barrel_roll(self):
        ...
```

Comment: With the amount of methods in my code, I'm afraid this option isn't really viable. My last resort would be to actually implement each method in every sub class and simply leave the non-implemented methods empty (with a single `pass` statement)

Comment: It sounds like you don't really want an abstract base class. They simply don't provide the option of "implement at least some, not necessarily all, of the abstract methods".

Comment: That's Unfortunate. I would have loved to use an abstract class to avoid instancing of the base class.